# Why does match not work while PartialEq/Eq works fine?

Tags: rust

I have this simple code:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Default, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Hash)]
struct NodeIndex(u32);

fn main() {
    let i = NodeIndex(5323);
    let from = NodeIndex(21030);
    let to = NodeIndex(21031);

    println!("from == i => {}, to == i => {}", from == i, to == i);

    match i {
        from => println!("1"),
        to => println!("2"),
        _ => println!("other"),
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
from == i => false, to == i => false
1
```

so `i != from`, `i != to`, but `match` call `from => println!("1"),`,
what is going on?

Comment: I think that you can use match only with literal.

Comment: [This code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=33255e4b59d8c42cf6bb73a42da829bb&version=stable&backtrace=0) does what you intended to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be easier to understand what's going on by looking at the compiler's warnings:

```
warning: unused variable: `from`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         from => println!("1"),
   |         ^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         to => println!("2"),
   |         ^^ this is an unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
note: this pattern matches any value
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         from => println!("1"),
   |         ^^^^

warning: unused variable: `to`
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         to => println!("2"),
   |         ^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         _ => println!("other"),
   |         ^ this is an unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
note: this pattern matches any value
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         from => println!("1"),
   |         ^^^^
```

Basically, the identifiers `from` and `to` *do not* refer to the values contained in the bindings. They are *new* bindings that happen to match anything. The same thing happens with new identifier names:

```
match i {
    x => println!("1"),
    y => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("other"),
}
```

Since the program always matches the first case, "1" is always printed.

You can get the expected result by declaring `from` and `to` as `const`:

```
const from: NodeIndex = NodeIndex(21030);
const to: NodeIndex = NodeIndex(21031);
```

Or by using object literals directly:

```
match i {
    NodeIndex(21030) => println!("1"),
    NodeIndex(21031) => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("other"),
}
```

If the values of `from` and `to` are only known in runtime, you can use `if`/`else` statements:

```
if n == from {
    println!("1");
} else if n == to {
    println!("2");
} else {
    println!("other");
}
```

... or add `if` clauses during the match (which are evaluated in run-time):

```
match i {
    n if n == from => println!("1"),
    n if n == to => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("other"),
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I can not use `const`, because of I calculate those values in real program, so I have to use `if else` in this case?

Comment: @user1244932, you can use `match i { x if x == v1 => ... , x if x == v2 => ...,}` syntax

Comment: @user1244932 I've updated the answer. Indeed, you can either use if/else or add `if` clauses to the match cases.