# Why does the order of parameters matter when using the matches! macro?

Tags: rust, enums, comparison

I'm trying to compare a variable of enum type stored in a vector of structs, with a variable of the same type passed into my function as a parameter. So, both enums are stored in variables. However, I'm getting unexpected results.  I'm using the `matches!()` macro for comparison.  Can anyone explain this behaviour?

```
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
}


fn main() {
    let a = Foo::A;
    if matches!(a, Foo::A) { println!("expected") }
    if matches!(a, Foo::B) { println!("not expected 1") }
    if matches!(Foo::B, a) { println!("not expected 2") }

    let b =  Foo::B;
    if matches!(a, b) { println!("not expected 3") }
}
```

Output:

```
expected
not expected 2
not expected 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.matches.html) macro is not symmetrical**: the first operand is the expression to be tested and the second operand is a [*pattern*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html) to try matching the first operand against. If this order is not followed, the results will likely be unexpected.

While the first two `matches!` are well formed and do what you expect, the third and fourth one are most likely not what you want.

```rust
matches!(Foo::B, a) // test `Foo::B` against pattern `a`
matches!(a, b) // test `a` against pattern `b`
```

The expression to be tested is the literal value `Foo::B`, and the pattern is a new identifier, `a` in the third example and `b` in the fourth one. Since the pattern is only an identifier, it will match any expression. It does not relate at all to the variables `a` and `b` declared beforehand. The code below would still compile even when `b` did not exist.

```rust
let a = Foo::A;
matches!(a, b);
```

Note also that these `if` statements would print warnings, because a new variable was created from the pattern, but was not used.

```
warning: unused variable: `a`
 --> src/main.rs:7:25
  |
7 |     if matches!(Foo::B, a) { println!("not expected 2") }
  |                         ^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_a`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
```

See also:

- [Why does match not work while PartialEq/Eq works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889689/why-does-match-not-work-while-partialeq-eq-works-fine)
- [Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225958/why-is-this-match-pattern-unreachable-when-using-non-literal-patterns)

Comment: Thank you!  The links you provided should answer my follow-up question, which is how does one then compare enums held in variables in a match statement.  I think the (n if n == a) pattern should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [E_net4 the curator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-the-curator) for the helpful answer.  I can now get the behaviour I expect using the following:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
}


fn main() {
    let a = Foo::A;
    let b = Foo::B;

    let s = match a {
        n if n == b => "a matches b",
        n if n == a => "a matches a",
        _ => "no match"
    };
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

With output:

```
a matches a
```

Comment: Note that there isn't much benefit from using a `match` expression in this example. The same can be achieved with a sequence of if-else expressions (e.g. `let s = if a == b { "a matches b" } else if a == a { "a matches a" } else { "no match" };`). `if` guards in match braces are useful when combined with more complex patterns.